# Update SQLite table based on data in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have two tables in SQLite which look like this

```
TABLE_X    
____________________
| id | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
| 10 | 99 | 03 | 04 | 00 |
| 60 | 88 | 20 | 30 | 40 |


TABLE_Y
___________     
| id | C2 |
| 10 | 11 |
| 60 | 22 |
```

I am trying to write query to update records on Table X based on records in Table Y
The condition for the updateis something like the following

```
update table_x
   set table_x.c1 = 100,
       table_x.c2 = table_y.c2
 where table_x.id = table_y.id
```

But when I try to do this I get an error message saying

> **NO such column: table_y.c2**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The deleted answer was correct about the cause of the error: a relation identifier must be *introduced* (e.g. with FROM/JOIN) in a query before it can be used.

While SQLite does *not* support `UPDATE..JOIN` (so there is no way to introduce the lookup relation directly), a dependent sub-query can be used to simulate the effect:

```
update table_x
   set c1 = 100,
       c2 = (select y.c2 from table_y as y
             where y.id = table_x.id)
```

Note that *unlike* a proper `UPDATE..JOIN`, if the sub-select fails to find a match then NULL will be assigned.

YMMV.

Comment: Thanks fro the reply but unfortunately it does not work I keep getting the following error **near ".":syntax error**

Comment: @KhurramMajeed Whoops, I corrected the answer. The relation for the set columns must *not* be specified (it is implied that they are columns of the update target relation).

Comment: To limit update to `id` found in `table_y`, just add a `WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table_y)`.