# Selecting data from one table based upon matching values in another

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to select data from one table based upon data in another.  My code follows that provided as an answer in:  [Update SQLite table based on data in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713678/update-sqlite-table-based-on-data-in-another-table)

But I can't get it to produce the results I was hoping for.  My statement is shown below:

```
c.execute("SELECT item1, item2, item3 FROM TableA WHERE xyz IS NULL AND item1 = (SELECT item1 FROM TableB) AND item2 = (SELECT item2 FROM TableB) AND item3 = (SELECT item3 FROM TableB)"
```

I'm trying to select all matching results from TableA, where item1,item2, & item 3 in tableB match with those in TableA + where TableA's xyz value is NULL.

```
*TableA*

item1  |  item2 |  item3     |  xyz

banana | apple  | pear       | NULL
carrot | potato | sausage    |  1
cat    | dog    | bird       | NULL
fish   | squid  | tortoise   |  4


*TableB*

item1  |  item2 |  item3

banana | apple  | pear
cat    | dog    | bird
fish   | squid  | tortoise
foo    | bar    | deadbeef
```

So, I'm trying to select:

```
banana, apple, pear 
cat, dog, bird
```

But my statement is only returning the first match from tableB:

i.e. `banana, apple, pear`; and doesn't continue searching the rest of the items from table B.

Why is this happening and could it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have SQLite at hand now, so please forgive typos... But won't an [inner join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm) be the good solution for that ?

```
c.execute("""SELECT item1, item2, item3 
               FROM TableA JOIN TableB USING (item1,item2,item3)
               WHERE xyz IS NULL")
```

This join will match rows on identical *"triplet"* `(item1,item2,item3)`.

---

If you only have the three column `item1..3` in common to your two tables, you might even want to go to a *natural join*:

```
c.execute("""SELECT item1, item2, item3 
               FROM TableA NATURAL JOIN TableB
               WHERE xyz IS NULL")
```

This is an inner join implicitly made on the *columns having the same name* in both of the tables. 
I'm not a big fan of this though, as it might become a time bomb ready to explode the day someone inadvertently add some columns to your tables...

Comment: Brilliant, thank-you (also for the link & advice).  Both examples worked, but I think I'll heed your advice and stick with the first!